# Jira Plugin Development

Tags: java, plugins, jira

How can I know the path of my resource file. For example in my plugin skeleton I have a properties file such jtt.properties, when I upload this plugin to any jira instance, how can I know the path of my propertis file.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "Practical JIRA Plugins", O'Reilly:

The full name of the properties file is the plugin src/main/resources directory plus the location value with periods replaced by directory separators and .properties appended,
i.e. src/main/resources/com/mycompany/jira/plugins/i18n/en_US.properties